# Does an empty dictionary inside an empty list make the list Not-empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have this list:

```
li = [{}]

if li:
   print 'yes'

#Output - yes
```

I, wrongly, thought that it would not output anything as it is an empty thing(falsiness). Now, how do I check for its emptiness?

Comment: Same thing as `li=[None]` prints Yes. The list isn't empty, contains some item.

Comment: You need use `any()` like `if any(li): print 'Yes'` to check.

Comment: Your list is not empty, it has one element. Try `len([{}])` to see this.

Comment: @Dan So I need to use `if len([{}][0])` for checking its emptiness ?

Comment: No use `any()` as shaik suggested. Why do you have a list with an empty dictionary in it? Are you going to add more dictionaries to the list? Would you consider this to be 'empty' as well `[{}, {}]`?

Comment: @dan A deep nested JSON consists of these things, I wanted to eliminate them by simply checking their emptiness but this stumped me. `[{}, {}]` - The level of my intelligence(empty) says it is empty... :) . As per your suggestion I would use `any`

Comment: @Mr.President then `any()` will work as it checks each element to see if it is falsey and if any are not, it returns `True`. Be warned though that it will also think `[0, False]` is 'empty' whereas `[[[]]]` is not so you need to decide if that is a problem for you.

Comment: @Dan Oh, now, I got it why you asked for `[{}, {}]`. My apologies for idiotic answer. My structure would only have `[{}]`, I have checked the JSON thoroughly. I guess `any` would work effectively now.

Comment: @Mr.President just btw, why are you using python 2? Unless you have a really good reason, you should move to python 3.

Comment: @Dan I have a Python 2.7 book from which I am learning, but you are right, may be I should switch for efficient and faster Python 3.

Comment: @Mr.President please stop learning from that book! Python 2 is more than a decade old and is being deprecated next year. You are doing yourself a massive disservice.

Comment: @Dan OMG, next year!! I would finish this small project next week and would switch to Python 3 on your advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `[{}]` is your only case, then `any([{}])` returns `False`. However, it will also return `False` for `[0]` which might not be what you want and it will return `True` for `[[{}]]`.

If you want to check that a list contains only empty items recursively, try this:

```
def is_empty_recursive(collection):
    try:
        if len(collection) == 0:
            return True
    except TypeError:
        # This will happen if collection is not a collection for example len(0) will cause this exception
        return False

    return all(is_empty_recursive(item) for item in collection)
```

Now you can use it like

```
li = [{}]

if not is_empty_recursive(li):
   print("yes")
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the limitations of using `any` for certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

to check for emptiness, you could look at each thing contained in your list:

```
emptydict = [{}]
for obj in emptydict:
    if obj:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

to understand why sets operate a certain way, you could briefly review set theory(does a set of all sets contain itself?):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set

Comment: Thank you, Sir, for explaining it through set theory.

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple ways depending on what you want to achieve. You could simply use:

```
li = []
print(li)
```

If nothing is returned there is nothing there.